# Preview mode of AucTeX fails on displayed equations but not on inline math

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm trying to use the preview mode in AucTeX, but for some reason the rendering of equations are failing but inline math is rendering fine. When I look inside the directory with the preview images I see that the `.png` files which correspond to the equations don't exist.

Why would only the math inside the equation environments fail to be rendered?

Comment: It works for me. Can you provide an example?

Comment: What version of AUCTeX and Emacs are you using? Have you got any special configuration of AUCTeX?

Comment: I'm using Emacs 23.3, but I'm not sure about the version of AUCTex. It looks like the problem has to do with the fact that I've got a multifile document.

Comment: @Ranjit Have you set up [multifiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html) properly?

Comment: @Ranjit Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, i.e. a minimal example where the preview fails. If you provide this it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: No MWE after several months => too localized.